# Can a php session cookie be changed via javascript?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Hi,

I created a sesion in my php file like this and set a value every time the page is accessed:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["userstate"] = "online";
```

however, as the user closes the tab or moves away from my page I want that cookie to change its value to offline so in Javascript I did:

```
 document.cookie = "userstate=offline";
```

I tried but it didnt work. Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. The session cookie is just an unguessable unique id string that points to the session storage area on the server. You can change the cookie, but that will just break the pointer -- it will not change the contents of the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All that is stored in the browser's cookies is a session ID.

That ID is used to look up the data stored *on the server*; it is inaccessible to JavaScript and cannot be modified by JavaScript like that.

Comment: @CainNuke Correct.